# best practice for starting docker container at specific time

Tags: docker, docker-compose, celery

**Q: Is it possible to start a docker-container using celery-beat, so a celery task can be run?**

- I know this is a hack, but wanted an opinion on how best I can achieve my use-case
- I need to automatically start and stop a docker container every
  Saturday on a set schedule
- I would like to have the container active for 2
  hours (Sat 7:00 AM  --> Sat 9:00 AM)
- The docker container is a
  gateway to a system that only allows one connection (Any other
  connection is disconnected)
- It is used by other users, so this window is allocated to me to run my procedures
- Is there a way to achieve this with celery-beat
- Is there a scheduling concept in docker-compose I could use?
- Ideally I would like to configure this in my code, stead of the instance cronjob, etc.

Comment: You should be able to wrap a task that uses [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to run container. It should not be a problem. Similarly, you can configure your Celery beat to trigger this task at any point of time. Keep in mind that it will run container on the machine where the task is executed.

Comment: Thanks ran into a snag; Is it possible to get the docker containers that is running on the host machine from within a container? Or would I need to run this wrapper on the host machine